# Is there a fundamental link between Nash's equilibrium and Turing's halting problem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability, nash-equilibrium

Since Nash equilibrium exists, is there a computational analogue of this equilibrium point? I am trying to approach Nash equilibrium from computational point of view to see if the equilibrium point has some fundamental correspondence with the theory of computation.

Comment: The best computational analogue of Nash equilibrium is probably the class PPAD.  See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPAD_(complexity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPAD_(complexity)) and look specifically for "Nash equilibrium".  Roughly, given a 2-player non-zero sum game, the problem of finding a Nash equilibrium is in NP.  It's probably not NP-complete. Papadimitriou created PPAD to capture the complexity of problems such as this, which involve finding a fixed point of a given function (for which a fixed point is known to exist).  For more, see the paper domotorp links to in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, these two problems are quite unrelated. The halting problem is based on an argument that is similar to Russell's paradox, while the existance of the Nash equilibrium follows from Borsuk-Ulam. For some complexity results about computing an approximate Nash equilibrium, see, e.g., [Goldberg: A Survey of PPAD-Completeness for Computing Nash Equilibria](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2709).